# MobaXterm SOCKS5 proxy for SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, passwords, mobaxterm

I need to connect to a remote RHEL server using SSH, via a SOCKS 5 proxy.

Unfortunately MobaXterm wants to prompt for my proxy password every time and doesn't appear to provide the means to use any of the saved passwords nor prompt you to save it when entering.

As an alternative, the Tunnelling feature seemed promising. I had hoped that I could use this to create a localhost bound password-less SOCKS 5 proxy, that connects to the authenticated SOCKS 5 proxy but was unable to figure this out either.

Has anyone worked out if MobaXterm can indeed save proxy passwords or create a SOCKS 5 --> SOCKS 5 proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the version MobaXterm v20.4 Build 4480

exists an experimental feature for proxies including SOCKS5 proxy which seems to work very good without any issues yet.

[image]